# ASP.NET WebForms view engine unable to parse server-side tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I have the following line in an MVC view:

```
<meta name="msapplication-starturl" 
    content="<%= Url.BaseServerHttpUrl() + gaPinningCampaign %>" />
```

This simply renders out:

```
 <meta name="msapplication-starturl" 
     content="&lt;%= Url.BaseServerHttpUrl() + gaPinningCampaign %>" />
```

The way I found round it was to prepend an empty string do this:

```
<meta name="msapplication-starturl" 
     content="<%= "" + Url.BaseServerHttpUrl() + gaPinningCampaign %>" />
```

Any ideas why the parser is getting confused and what a cleaner way to get around this would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove  runat="server" from head tag,